# unity iOS app is rejected because of iAd

Tags: ios, iad, unity-game-engine

I am struggling with submitting my iOS app. 
I am using Unity 5.1.1f1 version to build my iOS app but it gets rejected because of ads. I used Unity built-in **ADBannerView** to show ads. Even thought I see a test-ad on my device, Apple still rejects it saying:

**We still found that your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does not include ad functionality. This does not comply with the terms of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
Specifically, section 3.3.12 of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement states: 
..**

Some people say change your answer in itunesconnect to **NO** (**Does this app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)?**) and some say [modify some functions](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ios-advertising-identifier-rejection-faq.226187/)  in xCode (I did and my app still did not pass)

NOTE: I haven't tried changing itune answer (looks scary)

How can I overcome this last hurdle? 
Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: If you are using only iAd and no other advertising frameworks then you should select "No" for "Does this app use the IDFA" as iAd does not use this identifier.

Comment: Hey Randy. Thanks for your response. If I say NO to the question, will my ads still show in the app? I am using Unity ADBannerView (is this considered to be a third party?) Also should I still modify some functions that deal with ads (like the link that I referred) ?

Comment: The answer to this question is nothing to do with whether or not adds appear in your app. It is simply "does your app use the IDFA".  You need to give the correct answer for the ad library you are using. The correct answer for iAd is "no"

Comment: Thanks all!!! Hopefully this time it will get accepted